# Remove lines that doesn't contain numbers before the @ using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have like that:

```
abc@5004428
abcd12@62604
abcde@505779
```

But my file is larger than that.

So, I want to remove the whole line that contain "abc" and "abcde" becase they are before @ and they does not contain numbers.

More explained: I want to remove the whole line which value before @ doesn't contain numbers using Notepad++

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following regex to perform this and use `Replace Everything` while leaving the `Replace By` empty

```
^\D*@.*(\n|$)
```

- `^` represents the beginning of the line
- `\D*` represents zero or more non-numerics
- `@` literally is the arobase character
- `.*` will match the rest of the line greedily (until the end)
- `(\n|$)` will match either the end-of-the line or the line-breaker

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qJ7Y2M/3)**